# Dividir valor monetário por checkbox marcado

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho dúvida de como fazer para funcionar, marcar vários "checkbox" ou só um, inserir um valor no input "Total" e mostrar o resultado dividir, sem refresh na página, tentei com .on change, mas não consigo pegar a quantidade checkded e o valor e mostrar o valor dividido.

Exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var total = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
  $('.resultado').html(total);
});


$('input').on('change', function() {
  $('.resultado2').html(this.value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="usuario[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="usuario[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="usuario[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="usuario[]" value="1">
<input type="text" value="0">
<div class="resultado2"></div>
<div class="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Não precisa que seja monetário, apenas que divida...

Comment: Como alguém pontua negativo e nem me explica o porque? Ta querendo me prejudicar, má fé!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma simplificação no código:

```js
function calcula() {
  var total = $('#total').val();
  var qtd = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
  $('#resultado').html( total / qtd );
}
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', calcula );
$('#total').on('input', calcula );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="usuario[]" value="1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="usuario[]" value="2" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="usuario[]" value="3" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="usuario[]" value="4" checked>
<input type="text" id="total" value="0">
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Caramba velho, claro, todos "input". obrigado!

Comment: Vlw man! Vai me ajudar muito nos próximos

Comment: Uma dúvida, talvez boba, como recupero o valor?

Comment: @MarcelloInfoweb depende como vc vai usar. O valor foi calculado nessa linha: `$('#resultado').html( total / qtd );` nada impede de você criar uma variável armazenando `total / qtd`. (ou recuperar o valor da div usando o mesmo método que usamos para "escrever" nela)